# Invalid Geometry MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, gis, postgis

My multi polygon is constantly refused by mysql because it's invalid. 
However when previewed through online tools, it looks perfectly fine...
The mysql function `st_isValid` is returning false to be more precise

[image: Multi Polygon]
Looking through various forums, `ST_makeValid` is something PostGis users use to fix that kind of problem. How would one, "fix" this polygon using mysql spatial functions or any easy tool for the matter.

Here is the geometry in geoJson:

```
{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -73.698313, 45.546876 ], [ -73.698462, 45.546844 ], [ -73.699371, 45.546608 ], [ -73.699627, 45.546491 ], [ -73.699793, 45.546463 ], [ -73.699896, 45.546472 ], [ -73.700075, 45.546481 ], [ -73.700498, 45.546624 ], [ -73.700588, 45.546606 ], [ -73.700742, 45.546527 ], [ -73.701113, 45.546223 ], [ -73.701124, 45.546191 ], [ -73.701085, 45.546137 ], [ -73.701111, 45.546092 ], [ -73.701238, 45.545984 ], [ -73.701366, 45.545957 ], [ -73.701648, 45.545965 ], [ -73.701891, 45.545956 ], [ -73.70197, 45.545941 ], [ -73.702086, 45.54587 ], [ -73.702321, 45.545699 ], [ -73.702444, 45.545534 ], [ -73.702512, 45.545478 ], [ -73.702581, 45.545343 ], [ -73.702645, 45.545288 ], [ -73.702683, 45.545216 ], [ -73.702683, 45.545207 ], [ -73.702569, 45.545094 ], [ -73.702316, 45.544992 ], [ -73.702318, 45.544894 ], [ -73.70237, 45.544849 ], [ -73.702378, 45.544842 ], [ -73.702387, 45.544812 ], [ -73.702489, 45.544731 ], [ -73.702642, 45.544668 ], [ -73.702758, 45.544676 ], [ -73.702912, 45.544757 ], [ -73.703027, 45.544793 ], [ -73.703142, 45.544802 ], [ -73.703258, 45.544801 ], [ -73.703501, 45.544765 ], [ -73.703616, 45.544711 ], [ -73.703807, 45.544584 ], [ -73.703948, 45.544404 ], [ -73.704191, 45.544269 ], [ -73.705047, 45.543988 ], [ -73.70556, 45.54414 ], [ -73.70565, 45.544122 ], [ -73.705777, 45.544005 ], [ -73.705908, 45.543959 ], [ -73.706044, 45.543856 ], [ -73.706165, 45.543846 ], [ -73.706212, 45.543824 ], [ -73.706391, 45.543788 ], [ -73.70666, 45.543769 ], [ -73.706814, 45.543742 ], [ -73.706916, 45.543706 ], [ -73.707044, 45.543616 ], [ -73.707197, 45.543427 ], [ -73.707286, 45.543273 ], [ -73.707349, 45.543129 ], [ -73.707375, 45.543003 ], [ -73.707489, 45.542823 ], [ -73.70754, 45.542787 ], [ -73.707578, 45.542718 ], [ -73.707624, 45.542532 ], [ -73.707743, 45.542414 ], [ -73.707756, 45.542391 ], [ -73.707837, 45.542312 ], [ -73.707695, 45.542218 ], [ -73.707799, 45.542165 ], [ -73.707964, 45.54223 ], [ -73.70864, 45.541779 ], [ -73.709086, 45.541334 ], [ -73.70926, 45.540994 ], [ -73.709678, 45.540647 ], [ -73.710124, 45.540184 ], [ -73.710752, 45.539606 ], [ -73.710862, 45.539522 ], [ -73.7119, 45.538719 ], [ -73.712186, 45.538533 ], [ -73.712343, 45.538382 ], [ -73.712576, 45.538295 ], [ -73.713026, 45.538201 ], [ -73.713466, 45.538008 ], [ -73.713586, 45.537784 ], [ -73.713871, 45.53767 ], [ -73.714244, 45.537593 ], [ -73.714528, 45.537489 ], [ -73.71485, 45.537429 ], [ -73.715157, 45.537406 ], [ -73.715391, 45.537291 ], [ -73.715417, 45.537247 ], [ -73.715547, 45.537176 ], [ -73.715665, 45.537051 ], [ -73.715795, 45.536972 ], [ -73.715863, 45.536802 ], [ -73.71592, 45.536523 ], [ -73.715915, 45.536208 ], [ -73.716052, 45.535814 ], [ -73.716071, 45.535535 ], [ -73.716052, 45.535247 ], [ -73.71588, 45.534939 ], [ -73.716084, 45.534977 ], [ -73.716442, 45.534999 ], [ -73.716836, 45.535129 ], [ -73.716882, 45.535364 ], [ -73.716829, 45.535435 ], [ -73.716683, 45.535641 ], [ -73.716334, 45.535808 ], [ -73.71619, 45.535914 ], [ -73.716214, 45.536004 ], [ -73.716249, 45.536158 ], [ -73.716494, 45.536656 ], [ -73.716476, 45.536871 ], [ -73.716406, 45.537123 ], [ -73.716443, 45.537204 ], [ -73.717134, 45.537221 ], [ -73.717826, 45.537202 ], [ -73.718647, 45.537139 ], [ -73.718905, 45.537079 ], [ -73.719008, 45.537053 ], [ -73.719393, 45.537021 ], [ -73.720214, 45.536967 ], [ -73.720718, 45.536775 ], [ -73.721323, 45.536638 ], [ -73.723005, 45.535883 ], [ -73.723043, 45.535883 ], [ -73.723865, 45.535308 ], [ -73.724449, 45.5349 ], [ -73.725114, 45.534367 ], [ -73.725856, 45.533826 ], [ -73.726142, 45.53364 ], [ -73.726247, 45.533533 ], [ -73.726299, 45.532958 ], [ -73.726355, 45.532743 ], [ -73.726475, 45.53251 ], [ -73.726659, 45.532296 ], [ -73.726867, 45.53219 ], [ -73.726906, 45.532164 ], [ -73.727198, 45.532158 ], [ -73.727213, 45.532158 ], [ -73.727599, 45.532099 ], [ -73.728068, 45.531727 ], [ -73.728224, 45.531647 ], [ -73.728484, 45.531461 ], [ -73.728553, 45.531246 ], [ -73.728529, 45.531156 ], [ -73.728517, 45.531128 ], [ -73.728353, 45.531037 ], [ -73.728277, 45.530964 ], [ -73.728266, 45.530892 ], [ -73.728721, 45.530591 ], [ -73.729368, 45.530292 ], [ -73.729717, 45.530161 ], [ -73.730596, 45.529819 ], [ -73.73101, 45.529617 ], [ -73.73141, 45.529504 ], [ -73.731832, 45.529509 ], [ -73.732443, 45.529696 ], [ -73.732702, 45.529555 ], [ -73.733496, 45.52896 ], [ -73.733746, 45.528693 ], [ -73.734217, 45.528221 ], [ -73.734641, 45.527614 ], [ -73.734958, 45.527149 ], [ -73.735257, 45.526991 ], [ -73.736568, 45.526177 ], [ -73.737348, 45.525664 ], [ -73.737667, 45.525694 ], [ -73.738211, 45.526006 ], [ -73.738313, 45.526043 ], [ -73.738646, 45.526038 ], [ -73.739047, 45.525862 ], [ -73.739423, 45.525624 ], [ -73.739645, 45.525446 ], [ -73.739881, 45.525206 ], [ -73.740005, 45.524811 ], [ -73.740078, 45.524389 ], [ -73.740203, 45.523976 ], [ -73.740336, 45.523752 ], [ -73.740421, 45.523661 ], [ -73.740493, 45.523583 ], [ -73.741125, 45.523383 ], [ -73.74173, 45.523246 ], [ -73.741829, 45.522824 ], [ -73.741822, 45.522572 ], [ -73.742126, 45.522134 ], [ -73.742277, 45.521686 ], [ -73.742565, 45.521392 ], [ -73.742617, 45.520807 ], [ -73.742951, 45.520181 ], [ -73.744178, 45.519114 ], [ -73.744184, 45.51911 ], [ -73.744569, 45.518803 ], [ -73.74484, 45.518716 ], [ -73.744966, 45.518817 ], [ -73.745869, 45.517954 ], [ -73.746613, 45.517296 ], [ -73.74691, 45.517173 ], [ -73.747035, 45.517309 ], [ -73.747053, 45.51767 ], [ -73.747219, 45.517671 ], [ -73.747682, 45.517595 ], [ -73.747788, 45.517435 ], [ -73.747865, 45.517399 ], [ -73.748441, 45.517451 ], [ -73.748557, 45.517398 ], [ -73.748778, 45.517229 ], [ -73.749537, 45.5165 ], [ -73.749915, 45.51618 ], [ -73.750334, 45.515761 ], [ -73.750655, 45.515162 ], [ -73.750665, 45.514712 ], [ -73.750769, 45.514047 ], [ -73.750946, 45.513581 ], [ -73.75157, 45.513155 ], [ -73.751765, 45.513032 ], [ -73.752117, 45.512747 ], [ -73.752464, 45.512688 ], [ -73.752745, 45.512691 ], [ -73.752954, 45.512513 ], [ -73.752951, 45.512072 ], [ -73.753383, 45.512203 ], [ -73.753531, 45.512197 ], [ -73.753563, 45.512196 ], [ -73.753833, 45.512118 ], [ -73.754196, 45.511933 ], [ -73.754596, 45.511775 ], [ -73.755124, 45.511637 ], [ -73.755124, 45.511664 ], [ -73.755043, 45.511816 ], [ -73.755029, 45.512491 ], [ -73.755398, 45.512558 ], [ -73.756062, 45.512664 ], [ -73.756843, 45.512673 ], [ -73.757022, 45.512675 ], [ -73.757356, 45.512597 ], [ -73.758469, 45.512069 ], [ -73.758612, 45.511963 ], [ -73.759013, 45.511769 ], [ -73.75918, 45.511753 ], [ -73.759238, 45.511457 ], [ -73.759422, 45.511216 ], [ -73.759592, 45.511065 ], [ -73.759903, 45.510879 ], [ -73.760382, 45.51065 ], [ -73.760742, 45.510582 ], [ -73.761129, 45.510469 ], [ -73.761283, 45.510438 ], [ -73.761231, 45.510405 ], [ -73.761135, 45.510343 ], [ -73.755167, 45.506485 ], [ -73.755064, 45.506523 ], [ -73.752055, 45.507622 ], [ -73.748701, 45.508835 ], [ -73.747916, 45.509124 ], [ -73.740198, 45.511933 ], [ -73.735099, 45.513786 ], [ -73.728501, 45.516087 ], [ -73.735899, 45.520728 ], [ -73.733579, 45.52237 ], [ -73.731767, 45.523673 ], [ -73.728065, 45.521351 ], [ -73.725348, 45.523671 ], [ -73.722848, 45.525778 ], [ -73.721705, 45.526745 ], [ -73.718494, 45.524743 ], [ -73.718088, 45.525066 ], [ -73.717292, 45.525696 ], [ -73.714647, 45.523987 ], [ -73.714558, 45.523931 ], [ -73.713114, 45.52516 ], [ -73.712405, 45.524875 ], [ -73.712005, 45.524693 ], [ -73.711113, 45.524223 ], [ -73.710785, 45.524028 ], [ -73.709259, 45.523045 ], [ -73.702788, 45.525374 ], [ -73.701599, 45.525801 ], [ -73.699039, 45.526713 ], [ -73.698205, 45.527013 ], [ -73.695128, 45.52806 ], [ -73.693888, 45.528364 ], [ -73.692614, 45.528591 ], [ -73.691609, 45.528713 ], [ -73.690335, 45.528797 ], [ -73.68906, 45.528803 ], [ -73.68808, 45.528755 ], [ -73.687082, 45.52866 ], [ -73.686373, 45.529235 ], [ -73.685703, 45.529704 ], [ -73.685171, 45.530131 ], [ -73.6833, 45.530567 ], [ -73.683117, 45.530608 ], [ -73.680603, 45.531184 ], [ -73.679687, 45.53139 ], [ -73.677974, 45.531786 ], [ -73.677103, 45.531982 ], [ -73.676413, 45.532125 ], [ -73.675417, 45.532251 ], [ -73.674756, 45.532307 ], [ -73.67352, 45.532325 ], [ -73.672612, 45.532299 ], [ -73.671688, 45.532209 ], [ -73.670994, 45.532123 ], [ -73.670372, 45.532011 ], [ -73.669885, 45.531883 ], [ -73.668872, 45.531592 ], [ -73.665397, 45.530594 ], [ -73.655305, 45.527667 ], [ -73.654584, 45.527464 ], [ -73.654545, 45.527413 ], [ -73.653898, 45.527224 ], [ -73.651026, 45.526388 ], [ -73.650751, 45.526307 ], [ -73.650361, 45.526975 ], [ -73.649993, 45.527604 ], [ -73.648908, 45.529464 ], [ -73.64819, 45.530719 ], [ -73.648546, 45.530826 ], [ -73.648152, 45.531403 ], [ -73.647684, 45.532154 ], [ -73.646582, 45.533875 ], [ -73.64578, 45.535135 ], [ -73.646015, 45.535174 ], [ -73.655549, 45.536747 ], [ -73.655702, 45.536773 ], [ -73.660609, 45.537587 ], [ -73.661152, 45.537677 ], [ -73.664283, 45.5382 ], [ -73.664934, 45.538308 ], [ -73.665077, 45.538331 ], [ -73.677017, 45.540292 ], [ -73.677199, 45.540322 ], [ -73.691123, 45.542604 ], [ -73.693725, 45.543364 ], [ -73.694021, 45.54349 ], [ -73.695828, 45.544494 ], [ -73.697563, 45.546075 ], [ -73.69764, 45.546156 ], [ -73.69827, 45.546831 ], [ -73.698313, 45.546876 ] ], [ [ -73.751959, 45.517552 ], [ -73.751979, 45.517228 ], [ -73.75238, 45.516468 ], [ -73.752415, 45.516063 ], [ -73.75269, 45.515175 ], [ -73.752875, 45.514916 ], [ -73.753071, 45.514747 ], [ -73.753395, 45.514571 ], [ -73.753709, 45.514268 ], [ -73.753955, 45.514154 ], [ -73.753993, 45.514154 ], [ -73.754813, 45.514145 ], [ -73.756053, 45.514212 ], [ -73.756309, 45.514206 ], [ -73.75655, 45.514344 ], [ -73.756774, 45.514625 ], [ -73.756819, 45.514887 ], [ -73.757024, 45.515483 ], [ -73.757026, 45.515987 ], [ -73.756854, 45.516219 ], [ -73.756142, 45.516581 ], [ -73.755854, 45.516857 ], [ -73.755478, 45.517087 ], [ -73.754019, 45.517647 ], [ -73.753336, 45.517846 ], [ -73.752923, 45.517995 ], [ -73.752551, 45.517991 ], [ -73.752245, 45.517933 ], [ -73.75198, 45.517768 ], [ -73.751959, 45.517552 ] ] ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

`ST_buffer` is the easiest way to fix those strange problems in raw MySQL. However, the cost is that its extremely demanding.

`ST_buffer(geometry,0.00001)` By using this function, you are basically recreating the polygon but with a delta distance of .00001 which is extremely small. Using 0 do not work.

[More documentation on ST_buffer can be found here](http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-intro/geometry_returning.html#st-buffer)

However, I'm not sure to like this solution, if someone has a better idea. Feel free to correct me.

Comment: This silently removes the island from the geometry.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the geometry is represented by a `Polygon` with a hole outside the exterior. It should be a `MultiPolygon` with two exterior rings. This can be fixed in the JSON (see examples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON)).

With PostGIS, it can be fixed by rebuilding the polygons with:

```
SELECT ST_CollectionHomogenize(ST_Polygonize(ST_Boundary(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(json))))
```

Which returns a valid MultiPolygon. I'm not sure if MySQL offers any of these functions.